# The dollar ($) prefixed field '$divide' in is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update a field `seconds_until_start` by a calculation of two other fields. This doesn't seem to work in mongodb in the way that seems most intuitive. Any suggestions what else I can do are appreciated.

```
db.price_scrape.update({"timestamp": {"$exists": true}},
  {"$set": {
      seconds_until_start: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$marketstarttime", "$timestamp"]}, 1000]}
  }},
multi=true)
```

`The dollar ($) prefixed field '$divide' in 'seconds_until_start.$divide' is not valid for storage.`

Comment: [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) is an aggregation operator, you can't use it in an `update`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field) for the options for using other fields' values in an update.

Comment: it doesn't really answer the question in your link as it only composes a new field from two others, but without any operator

Comment: Short answer is that it isn't directly supported so you need to use one of the approaches in the link based on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mongo version, if it's not v4.2+ your query won't work.

As @JohnnyHK specified in the comment ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field))

Check the first answer which gives an insight into how you can write your query in lower versions on Mongo DB